# Auto complete on hierarchically related fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch, data-structures, solr

Am working on building an autocomplete feature for a dashboard use case. The size of filters will be in 10's and cardinality could be huge. As you might know, ES and SOLR  solve this problem with various approaches like prefix, Suggested, Edge Ngram etc. But I believe none of these consider the relation between multiple filters. For example, suppose we have a simple data set

Id -> Dept (1:n)
Dept -> Item (1:n)

Then essentially if the user inputs part of id, we should show autocomplete for that which is very trivial but on the user selecting from the autocomplete suggested Id list we should also list all Dept related to selected Id.

Id - (1,2,3)
Dept - (21,22,23,24,25,26)
Item - (100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111)

let's say the relationship is like

Id  Dept     Item
1   21      100,101
    22      102,103
2   23      104,105
    24      106,107
3   25      108,109
    26      110,111

Then selecting 1 in ID should list 21,22 in dept field, then selecting dept 21 should display 100,101

Am not looking for any solution in the UI layer rather in the backend. Am considering implementing b tree structure to solve the problem, before to that wanted to know if any open source tool that can solve this problem.

Comment: Solr has a [PathHierarchyTokenizer which allows](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-PathHierarchyTokenizer) splitting the path for each document when indexing, and there's multiple ways of [doing hierarchical faceting](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting) - which gives you the counts for each level in the hierarchy as you're issuing queries. Would any of those be suitable?

Comment: Thank you for the response, but don't think this that would suit. We don't need to tokenize any input. The input is already tokenized to columns and we need to just build the relationship

Comment: The idea is that you have a field that contain the relationship, meaning that an `Item` contains the hierarchy up to the root. You then tokenized and facet on this field.

Comment: Your UnitOfRetrieval is the item? For earch item the Id and the Dept is unique? Your filters will work on the items?